# Can i detect and track/record which USB device was used?

Tags: usb, keyboard

I have PC with 2 keyboards (1of them is scanner which is detected as keyboard) and i would like people to use scanner for scaning  barcode , but they are still able to use main keyboard (which i cannot unplug) is there possibility to track and recod to some file which devicec was used ?

Comment: (1) What is the OS? (2) "main keyboard (which i cannot unplug)" -- Maybe you (with our help) can disable it on the software level; still the question is about tracking/recording.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

- How does the data go *from the scanner to recorded data*?
- Where is data recorded (spreadsheet, database, etc.)?

The barcode reader *software* might be able to add a value in an additional column for each scan. If the existing application cannot be modified, check one of the many [free barcode reader applications](https://thegeekpage.com/free-barcode-reader-scanner-softwares/) to see if they can work with your database.

[image: Scanned or Keyboard?]